# Filter data using input value

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to filter data according to input value. I want to create an array with an objects but im getting array of [object Object].

First Im creating an empty Array:

```
let beersArray = [];
```

Later during creating elements I want to add to array an object with item name:

```
  function displayAllBeers(data) {
    beersArray = data
      .map((beer) => {
        beersContainer.innerHTML += `
        <div class='beerContainer'>
            <h3 class='name'>${beer.name}</h3>
            <img src='${beer.image_url}'></img>
            <p>${beer.description}</p>
            <button class="addFavBtn">Favourite</button>
            </div>
            `;
        return { name: beer.name };
      })
      .join("");
  }
```

Finally I add event listener to the input and want to filter the result

```
  searchInput.addEventListener("input", (e) => {
    const value = e.target.value;
    console.log(beersArray);
    beersArray.forEach((beer) => {
      const isVisible = beer.includes(value);
      beer.element.classList.toggle("hide", !isVisible);
    });
  });
```

I'm getting error:

> app.js:17 Uncaught TypeError: beersArray.forEach is not a function
> at HTMLInputElement. (app.js:17:16)

If I'm trying to do

```
Array.from(beersArray)
```

It puts in array every single letter as an element.

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You are building an array of `{ name: beer.name }`, then joining it into a string?

Comment: You have a `.join("")` so your `beerArray` is a string and not an array

Comment: Hint : the error mean "beersArray is not an array"